# CSS Text doesn't wrap?

Tags: css, overflow, whitespace

I'm developing a web app and in one of the `<div>s` on my page, the text doesn't wrap, instead it just overflows.

Now, the `<div>` has 2 stages: one where it is not expanded, and one where it is. 
When it is not expanded, I use the following CSS:

```
div.todo-item-title{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 90%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Using this CSS, I achieve the following effect:

[image: When the div is not expanded]

Basically it has a `max-width: 90%` (so that it doesn't go out of the box), `overflow: hidden` (so that the overflow is hidden), `white-space: nowrap` (so that the text doesn't wrap), and `text-overflow: ellipsis` (so that it shows the 3 dots on the end). And this result is exactly what I want.

Now, in the 2nd state, I extend the height of the `<div>`'s parent (the black box that you see on the image), and I **want the text to show fully and to wrap when necessary**.

So this is the CSS that I used on the text:

```
div.todo-item-title{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: none;
    text-overflow: initial;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: auto; 
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}
```

So, there I have:

- Set `max-width` to `none`, since I want the text to wrap
- Set `white-space` to `normal` so that it does wrap when necessary
- Set `overflow` to `auto` so that it shows the scrollbar when it eventually becomes too long.

But, now it looks like this:

[image: 2nd stage]

**For some reason, it still doesn't wrap.** What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It does not wrap because you have a long word with no spaces.

In this case, use:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.